# Inheritance constructor safety in C++

Tags: inheritance, c++11, constructor, default-constructor

I have this hierarchy :

```
struct Params { int k = 17; };
struct A
{
    A(Params& par): _p(par)
    { }

    Params& _p;
};

struct B: public A
{
    using A::A;
    int c{this->_p.k};
};

int main()
{
    Params p;
    B b(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Can I rest assured that `A::_p` will always be initialized before calling it in the declaration of `B::c` ?

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, `A::_p` comes from the base class, so it has to be initialized before the derived class starts constructing.

Comment: Thanks! You should put this as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be initialized.

The base class has to be fully constructed before the derived class starts to be constructed. So as long as the constructor from `A` initialized `A::_p`, the derived classes will always* see it fully initialized.

[*] Of course, with enough effort you can always break things; for example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/196a5b0217efbbb1
There I used the comma operator to call `B::foo()` before anything can be constructed; luckily the compiler detected it as a warning.